# In Lotusscript, how can I email a form from a button and have all the form data included?

Tags: java, email, lotusscript

Using this code:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
 Dim session As New NotesSession
 Dim db As NotesDatabase
 Dim doc As NotesDocument
 Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
 Set doc = New NotesDocument( db )
 doc.Form = "hardware1"
 doc.SendTo = "email1"
 doc.Subject = "Here's the document you wanted"
 Call doc.Send( True )
End Sub
```

I am getting the actual form emailed but no data is included from the form.

Comment: If it's being mailed to someone's inbox, it will open using the default form there. Is that what you wanted or did you want to have it open using the hardware1 form?

Comment: Your comment is wrong... The `True` parameter in the send- command sais, that the form will be included in the mail... Only shared code and shared resources (images) will not be visible in the target database, the rest will look like in the "sending" database...

Answer (score 2):

In your example code you create a new document with form "hardware1" and send that empty document.

If the code is in a button in the form, then you can get the "current" document using the NotesUiWorkspace:

```
Dim ws as New NotesUiWorkspace
Set doc = ws.CurrentDocument.Document
'- here comes your send code
```

Take care: by default the send- command saves the document unless you set the property savemessageonsend to false `doc.savemessageonsend=false`

In additin the document may get some additional fields by sending it, that you do not want. In that case send a copy of the document:

```
Dim docMemo as NotesDocument
Dim ws as New NotesUiWorkspace
Set docMemo = New NotesDocument( db )
Set doc = ws.CurrentDocument.Document
Call doc.CopyAllItems( docMemo )
docMemo.Subject = "email"
docMemo.SaveMessageOnSend = False
Call docMemo.Send( True )
```